# External link to controller won't render .js.erb file Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can render a .js.erb file following an ajax request, but if I type this url into the browser:

http://localhost:3000/posts/11

with a Post model that has a show action defined as

```
def show
  respond_to :js
end
```

and a corresponding show.js.erb file, I get the following error:

ActionController::UnknownFormat at /posts/11
ActionController::UnknownFormat

I want to be able to generate links for users to copy and paste so that they can link to posts, but I can't get passed this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify format within your url:
[http://localhost:3000/posts/11.js](http://localhost:3000/posts/11)

To generate such a route "rails way" pass format option to path:

```
link_to post.title, post_path(id: post.id, format: :js)
```